# Rotating background image tiles in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a full screen rotating background with tiled images like this one:

```css
.overlay{
  position:fixed;
   background:url(https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png);
 background-repeat:repeat;
  -webkit-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -o-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -ms-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate-left{
    0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left{
    0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
</div>
```

Is there a trick to make the tiles to fill the whole screen in all positions?

Thank you for your help in anticipation.

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules or warnings - which you will have got when trying to paste your fiddle link.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Have you tried setting the css property `background-size`?

Comment: I've tried the background-size propeties but they seems not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size` will not work here because you are rotating a div, not the background itself.

Mathematically, if you want the child div to cover the entirety of parent div's area during animation you need to make sure the child's height and width are equal or grater to the diagonal distance between corners of parent element.

So, you can either [do the math](http://www.mathopenref.com/rectanglediagonals.html), or simply make it really big.

```css
body{ margin: 0; }

.parent{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay{
  background:url(https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png);
  background-repeat:repeat;
  -webkit-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -o-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  -ms-animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  animation:180s rotate-left infinite linear;
  width:1000%;
  height:1000%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate-left{
    0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -moz-transform-origin: top left; }
    100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -moz-transform-origin: top left; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left{
    0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -webkit-transform-origin: top left; }
}

@keyframes rotate-left{
    0%{ transform:rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%); transform-origin: top left; }
    100%{ transform:rotate(-360deg) translate(-50%, -50%); transform-origin: top left; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```